# SQL Server Reporting Services cannot access Active Directory

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, active-directory, openquery, adsi

I have a stored procedure that uses OPENQUERY with ADSI to access Active Directory like this.

```
SELECT ADsPath, displayName, sAMAccountName, mail, userPrincipalName, manager
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, '<LDAP://...>;(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user));manager,userPrincipalName,mail,sAMAccountName,displayName,ADsPath;subtree')
```

It executes successfully in SSMS but when I use it as a data source in an SSRS report, I get this.

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
> Query execution failed for dataset 'DSMAIN'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
> An error occurred while preparing the query
> "LDAP://...;(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user));manager,userPrincipalName,mail,sAMAccountName,displayName,ADsPath;subtree"
> for execution against OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server
> "ADSI".

When I go back to the stored procedure and comment out the OPENQUERY part, the report will run successfully and remaining data will be displayed as normal. When I include the OPENQUERY again, it will stop working again.

Why does it run from SSMS but not from SSRS? It might be an issue with permissions, however the user account used by report server appears to be able to access Active Directory elsewhere (e.g. ADUC).

Comment: SSRS isn't executing the query, SQL Server is. When you're using SSMS are you logging in with a Windows/AD account? Is the data source using SQL Login credentials (as in an SQL username and password)? When an SQL Login is being used it will be trying to instantiate the ADSDSOObject using SQL Server's service account.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning In SSMS I use Windows Authentication. The data source of the report is set to use Windows credentials of a report server service account. Also tried to change this to use credentials of "the user viewing the report" and same. NB, I viewed the report with same account as used for Windows Authentication in SSMS - so even more strange why this account works in SSMS but not when inherited in SSRS. Never used SQL Server Authentication so it cannot be the cause.